# Unity : Check if UI Element in screen space canvas is visible or not

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'd like to know if a GameObject that is a UI Element (Button for example) in a screen space canvas is visible on screen or not.

Checking activeself is not good enough because if the element is active but has an inactive parent, it won't be visible.

I've been googling away for an hour without success. Should I check if all its parents are active ? That can be costly...

Can you kindly help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, checking whether all `GameObject`'s parents are active will definitely work, but it can be a bit costly. Anyway, there's a much better option.

- `GameObject.activeSelf` shows whether the `GameObject` is active itself, which returns `true` even if any of its parents is disabled.
- `GameObject.activeInHierarchy` shows whether `GameObject` is active in the hierarchy, so it returns `true` if any of its parents is disabled. That's what you need.

Here `Parent` is `inactive` and `GameObject` is `active`. `GameObject.activeSelf` is `true`, and `GameObject.activeInHierarchy` is `false`. (though it violates naming rules)

[image]

Additionally, note that neither the `GameObject` being `UI`, nor `Canvas` being in `Screen space` matters